# Is there a way to declare a Result that accepts a type implementing FromStr as the error?

Tags: rust

I'd like to write this kind of `Result`:

```
use std::result::Result;
use std::str::FromStr;

type MyResult<T> = Result<T, FromStr>;
```

This is not valid. Is there a way to express this?

Answer (score 2):

You might *try* to express it as:

```
type MyResult<T, U: FromStr> = Result<T, U>;
```

But the compiler would complain that:

```
warning: bounds on generic parameters are not enforced in type aliases
 --> src/main.rs:4:21
  |
4 | type MyResult<T, U: FromStr> = Result<T, U>; 
  |                     ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(type_alias_bounds)] on by default
  = help: the bound will not be checked when the type alias is used, and should be removed
```

Which means that you shouldn't do it this way. Note, however, that `FromStr` already contains a `Result`:

```
pub trait FromStr {
    type Err;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err>;
}
```

Maybe you should consider using it directly instead?

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to create a result that accept String and &str but maybe my understanding of the differences between those two is not deep enough (yet) :)

Comment: @Geob-o-matic `type MyResult<'a, T> = Result<T,`[`Cow<'a, str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)`>;`

Comment: Thanks @Tim, time to dig into `Cow` then ^^

Comment: @Geob-o-matic `Cow<str>` is what you are after if the error can be either a `String` or a `&str`. Depends on your specific use case, but in general it's very useful.